# Why Pug isn't showing any message when I do res.redirect after req.flash?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm creating a simple CRUD in Node, Express with PUG as template engine. Whenever an operation is done or failed, I use `req.flash("name","message")` in the .js file and after that I user res.redirect to specific page.
But after redirect, I can't see the message I want to show in alert.

Initially, I have same problem with this question: [Connect flash not displaying messages in Pug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283467/connect-flash-not-displaying-messages-in-pug)
But after I modified my code to the solution, still I don't get any messages.

Here's my code of Index.js:

```
...
const flash = require('connect-flash');
...
...
...
app.use(flash());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.errs = req.flash("error");
  res.locals.infos = req.flash("info");
  next();
});
...
...
...
```

Here's my code to the req, res usage inside POST method to save a document to a collection in MongoDB:

```
 Category.findOne({title: req.body.title}, (err, doc)=>{
        if(doc){
          res.render('admin/add_category', {
            errors: [{msg: 'Category already exists.'}],
            category: req.body.title
          });
        }
        else{
          var cat =  new Category({
            title: req.body.title,
            slug: req.body.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
          })

          cat.save((err)=>{
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            req.flash('info', 'category added'); //doesn't work
            res.redirect('/categories');
          })
        }
```

Here's my pug to show the flash.

```
if infos
  for info in infos
    div.alert.alert-info #{ info }
if errs
  for error, i in errs
    div.alert.alert-danger #{ error }
```

This pug file for showing the flash message is called nav.pug, it's included to the main page using `include ../includes/nav.pug`

I just want to make sure the message is showing to the page after redirect. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading Nick Gagne's answer, I tried to find out about session.
It turns out I need to change my express-session middleware setting. Because the `cookies: { secure: true}` the website needs to run in https, but unfortunately I run the server on localhost, that means when I changed to `cookies { secure: false }` the flash message will shows.
Final code:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {secure: false }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from looking at your code, but are you using the cookieParser and session middleware as recommended on the [connect-flash GitHub page](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash)?

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session({ cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}));
  app.use(flash());
});
```

The problem is that Express by default is stateless, so when you instruct the browser to redirect, it will send a new request to /categories, but Express will have no way of knowing that this request is part of the same "session", and so is unable to load the flash message.

Comment: I don't use cookieParser and session middleware, but when I tried your code, it says "`app.configure` is not a function". And I have question, what is the use of parameter you passed into `cookieParser()` function?

Edit: your example is not relevant to my code, it's Express 3 code. I'm using Express 4

Comment: I use `express-session` module but not cookieParser.